# User-defined keys in process.env is undefined in JavaScript Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions, terraform

I'm deploying an HTTP Trigger function to Azure Function but when I'm trying to access entries in `process.env` it returns `undefined`. It does work in the local emulator but does not when deployed on Azure.

---

### Test running the function locally and on Azure.

I've tested it with a very simple HTTP function.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest
): Promise<void> {
  context.log(process.env.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL);

  context.res = {
    body: process.env.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
  };
};

export default httpTrigger;
```

#### Running Locally

When running **locally** it does output value set in `local.settings.json`

```
[2021-09-11T13:41:27.737Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b9a303aa-5d14-403c-b841-4851f00beb65)
[2021-09-11T13:41:27.768Z] service_account@local.settings.json
[2021-09-11T13:41:27.848Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger' (Succeeded, Id=b9a303aa-5d14-403c-b841-4851f00beb65, Duration=126ms)
```

#### Run on Azure

But when running **on Azure** it output `undefined` (from Monitor > Logs of individual function in Azure portal)

```
2021-09-11T13:26:40Z   [Information]   HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2021-09-11T13:26:40Z   [Information]   undefined
```

(I ran it via URL from the Portal and the response is `500`)

#### Log the whole `process.env` (on Azure)

I'm curious that does it affect other env so I'm trying to log out the whole `process.env`

```
context.log(process.env)
```

As you can see there's not a single custom-defined env present. (I've omitted some values)

```
2021-09-11T13:26:40Z   [Information]   HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2021-09-11T13:26:40Z   [Information]   { ServiceName: 'service',
  PWD: '/',
  Fabric_NetworkingMode: 'Other',
  Fabric_Id: '',
  ASPNETCORE_URLS: 'http://localhost:9091',
  AzureWebJobsScriptRoot: '/home/site/wwwroot',
  Fabric_ServiceName: 'service',
  CONTAINER_NAME: '',
  Fabric_Epoch: '',
  SUDO_UID: '0',
  Fabric_NodeIPOrFQDN: '',
  HOST_VERSION: '3.1.4.0',
  MESH_INIT_URI: '',
  DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER: 'true',
  SHLVL: '0',
  Fabric_ApplicationName: '',
  Fabric_CodePackageName: '',
  Fabric_ReplicaId: '',
  SUDO_COMMAND:
   '/azure-functions-host/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost',
  Location: '',
  WEBSITE_HOME_STAMPNAME: '',
  ASPNETCORE_VERSION: '3.0.0',
  ResourceGroupName: '',
  TERM: 'xterm',
  languageWorkers__python__defaultRuntimeVersion: '3.6',
  HOME: '/home',
  LANG: 'C.UTF-8',
  Fabric_ServiceDnsName: '',
  LocalSitePackagesPath: '',
  CodePackageName: '',
  CONTAINER_IMAGE_URL: '',
  SubscriptionId:
   '',
  SUDO_GID: '0',
  WEBSITE_PLACEHOLDER_MODE: '1',
  CONTAINER_ENCRYPTION_KEY: '',
  ResourceName: '',
  ResourceType: '',
  WEBSITE_CLOUD_NAME: '',
  WEBSITE_STAMP_DEPLOYMENT_ID: '',
  USER: 'app',
  DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER: 'true',
  JAVA_HOME: '/usr/lib/jvm/zre-8-azure-amd64',
  SUDO_USER: 'root',
  SHELL: '/bin/bash',
  Fabric_ReplicaName: '0',
  HOSTNAME: '',
  PATH: '',
  CONTAINER_START_CONTEXT_SAS_URI: '',
  LOGNAME: 'app',
  _: '/usr/bin/setsid',
  FUNCTIONS_WORKER_DIRECTORY: '/azure-functions-host/workers/node' }
```

---

### Verify that Application settings are correctly set

You can see the entry is present in the **Configuration** tab of the Function App portal

[image: Azure Portal]

Also in `https://[function-app-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings` you can see the key is present (I've omitted the value as it's sensitive)

```json
{
  "deployment_branch": "master",
  "SCM_TRACE_LEVEL": "Verbose",
  "SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT": "60",
  "SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT": "7200",
  "SCM_BUILD_ARGS": "",
  "SCM_USE_LIBGIT2SHARP_REPOSITORY": "0",
  "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "",
  "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
  "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "",
  "GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL": "",
  "GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY": "",
  "LINE_NOTIFY_TOKEN": "",
  "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "",
  "AzureWebJobs.TimerTrigger.Disabled": "",
  "ScmType": "",
  "WEBSITE_SITE_NAME": "",
  "WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED": "",
  "WEBSITE_SLOT_NAME": "",
  "SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "",
  "REMOTEDEBUGGINGVERSION": "",
  "FUNCTIONS_RUNTIME_SCALE_MONITORING_ENABLED": "",
  "WEBSITE_AUTH_LOGOUT_PATH": "",
  "WEBSITE_AUTH_AUTO_AAD": "e"
}
```

---

### Deployment Method

I use Terraform with configuration as in [maximivanov/deploy-azure-functions-with-terraform](https://github.com/maximivanov/deploy-azure-functions-with-terraform) <sup>[GitHub]</sup> with the addition of merging env variables in `app_settings`.

```
variable "function_config" {
  type = map(string)
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function_app" {
  # Other arguments is the same as in the repo

  app_settings = merge({
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" = azurerm_application_insights.appInsights.instrumentation_key
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE"       = ""
  }, var.function_config)
}
```

```
function_config = {
  LINE_NOTIFY_TOKEN               = ""
  GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY = ""
  GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL       = ""
}
```

All env values above that you see in the Portal and Kudu are set by Terraform.

##### Additional Information

At first, I created all the resources via the VSCode extension. But later imported into Terraform state with the above configuration. (some resource were replaced)

---

### I have tried

- Restating the Function App from the portal
- Deleting all the functions and then redeploy them (I've deleted `dist` folder before redeploying to ensure that there's only new files)
- Force App Service Plan and Function App redeployment (by changing its name in Terraform) and then redeploy the same function.
- Change App Service Plan OS to Windows. (same results)
- Accessing the env with both `process.env.KEY` and `process.env["KEY"]`

I'm not sure what I did wrong or I should try next, please advise, Thanks!

---

#### Update

I've tried to deploy it to the separate Resource Group using only VSCode (resources are not created by Terraform) and it works! This's definitely the problem with my Terraform configuration (hence adding the `terraform` tag). So, in the meantime, I'll try comparing my Terraform configuration with the one created automatically by VSCode extensions.

Comment: Export an ARM template from the VSCode generated function app and compare it to your Terraform configuration to see what is different. Or you can also export an ARM template from the terraformed function app and diff the two templates, then reverse engineer back to terraform

Comment: @pkatsourakis Thank you, I just figured it out using a method similar to the one you suggested. Importing the resource into Terraform state and comparing it to my settings with Terraform plan. And I noticed a difference in config!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After try fixing things for almost 5 hours. I figured out it was a missing configuration in the Function App.

[`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_runtime) needs to be set to `node` (this was done automatically when deploying the resource directly from Visual Studio Code Extension)

**If you are using Terraform**

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "function" {
  # Other arguments

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "node"
    "SOME_OTHER_SETTINGS"      = "..."
  }
}
```

**If not config it within the Azure Portal**

[image]

Comment: Funny,  having the same issue with two Functions inside the same Function app. The only difference is the inbound trigger, one is HTTP, the other is Timer. HTTP is the original and it works fine, Timer is the new one, it sees process.env as undefined. The code is the same and both functions belong to the same VSCode project. Everything has been managed by VSCode. No Terraform involved.